# Prevent user from inadvertantly shifting app window on IPad display

Tags: ipad, safari, google-chrome

I'm using an iPad in a public kiosk situation running a lighting control software using Safari or Google Chrome browser. **Guided Access on the iPad is enabled** and a ****mask created** to block access to some buttons** on portions of the lighting control software but allow the users access to other lighting control buttons. However, when users press the unmasked buttons they can inadvertently move the browser window so it is out of alignment with the mask and the screen thus rendering the kiosk function unusable. How can I prevent the browser screen from being moved (example, **lock it in place**) on the iPad display so a user's finger push or swipe can't mistakenly change the browser window position? Unfortunately, the lighting software does not run in Full Screen mode.

Comment: Do you have access to change the HTML loaded in by the browser? - If so, you can add a meta tag specifying the viewport.

Comment: jksoegaard - Thanks for the reply. I'm using an iPad with an attached keyboard but have never edited any HTML code. I will try and figure it out but if you have a suggestion that might help, then that would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: This change is something you would do within the lighting control software - that is probably running on some sort of server type device (whether that be a turn-key box, Raspberry Pi or a 'regular' server).